# Get the updated value in laravel + vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a edit page : `http://localhost/smp/post/12`

[image]

**API ROUTE:**

```
Route::get('package', [ProductController::class, 'update']);
```

In `ProductController.php`

```
public function update(Request $request) {
    dd($request); // 
}
```

In `product.vue`

```
axios
.post("/promotion-platform/api/images/upload",{ 'id' : this.id })
          .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data);
})
```

eg: I fix the `name` box from '**Iphone 13**' to '**Iphone 12**'. And when I press update then I want to get the unique value I just modified.

Comment: You can Follow this link :: https://www.positronx.io/create-laravel-vue-js-crud-single-page-application/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on update method, you can return updated data.
On the vue side when you received success res.data you can over right it to do old data, then Vue's reactivity will update.

You can share also data of the component